# Angular Routing: Retrieving the latest route link inside the component state

Tags: angular2-routing

In order to provide a minimum example, suppose I have the following two routes specified in my RouterModule.forRoot, both linked to the same component **SomeComponent**.

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'one-path',  component: SomeComponent },
{ path: 'another-path', component: SomeComponent }];
```

And in the app html template I have the two router links along with the router-outlet

```
<a routerLink="/one-path">someLink</a> 
<a routerLink="/another-path">anotherLink</a>
...
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

What I want is have as part of the state of **SomeComponent** the last router link path due to which the component was rendered on the page. The purpose is to display a slightly different view depending on which link was used.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  let route_path = ... //this should either be 'one-path' or 'another-path' depending on which link was clicked

}
```

How can  this be  achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the actived route url observable. when component is initialize,  route_path will either be 'one-path' or 'another-path' depending on which link was clicked or if you are on the home route.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit { 
    route_path ='';  

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit() {

    this.route.url.subscribe((url) => {
         this.route_path = (url.length > 0 )? url[url.length-1].path: '';
      });

   }
}
```